# Fill QDoubleSpinBox from fixed point

Tags: qt, floating-point, fixed-point

I have some data available in fixed point 16.16 that I'd like to modify with a QDoubleSpinbox.

The problem is that whenever I convert my fixed point to a double there is the inevitable rounding issue.
`double = fixed / (double)65536`

Take for example `0.2`, in fixed point this is `0x00003333`, but when I put it into the QDoubleSpinBox it *shows* `0.19999694824188`.
But as soon as I touch the spinbox, it rounds to `0.2`.

How to make the QDoubleSpinBox round upon setValue?

---

The QDoubleSpinbox is behaving as designed, but my `QAbstractTableModel` was not.
When the controls of the spinbox are not visible, the table implicitly uses a QString to display the value given in the QVariant.
After implementing the `paint()` function with a fixed precision `setnum()` in the qstring, it works great!

Comment: See the decimals property. The spinbox rounds based on this value: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdoublespinbox.html#decimals-prop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick test shows that this works here:

```
double valueToSet = 0x00003333 / (double)65536;
ui.doubleSpinBox->setValue(valueToSet);
```

The UI shows 0.20. The spinbox does round when calling `setValue()`. You can check [the source code](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/widgets/widgets/qspinbox.cpp.html#_ZN14QDoubleSpinBox8setValueEd) yourself. I suggest stepping into the function with a debugger to see what is different for you.

Comment: See the edit. After looking to the source, I looked into the container of the spinbox. And there it was.